# Difference between static water level and water table level

Tags: civil-engineering, water-resources

Can anyone please explain to me the difference in the levels of static water and water table?

Answer (score 3):

- Static water level refers to the level of water (in a well for example) under normal, undisturbed, no-pumping conditions. Static water level is best determined when the well has not been pumped for several hours prior to measuring. You may get a false reading if the well was pumped just before the static water level is measured.
- Water Table Level is The level below which the ground is completely saturated with water Also called water level.

They mean the same just in geotechnical engineering they use the name "Water Table Level" because they are interested in the soil but when you talk about a well or dams you name it "Static water level" but they are the same they mean the level of water.

Comment: I had another query regarding this. In what case is static water level above water table level and in what case it is below the water table level?

Comment: The terms are similar they are only used in different fields or problems so when you say static water level you use it to describe the water level in a dam or well, but when you say water table level you are using it for soil.